# $a$ is a non isolated singularity of $f (z)$

Tags: singularity-theory

If a point $a$ is a non-isolated singularity of a function $f(z)$ and $|f(z)|$ is bounded in some neighbourhood of $a$ then what kind of singularity of $f(z)$ occurs at $a$?

1. Removable singularity
2. Essential singularity
3. Non removable
4. Non essential

Thank for answer in advance. ..

Comment: Do we assume your function is holomorphic on its domain of definition?

Comment: If we take f is holomorphic in its domain of definition then it is analytic then there is no question regarding singularity. Am I right?

Comment: It cannot be essential by Big Picard's theorem.